# Cancellation with scalars in vector space, a useless law?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

In typical textbooks on vector spaces the axioms are stated and then several algebraic identities are proven. Among them are the cancellation properties
$$
 x + y = x + z \mbox{ implies } y = z
$$
and $y + x = z + x$ implies $y = z$, and also that $\lambda x = \lambda y$ implies $x = y$ for $\lambda \ne 0$, but I think the following also holds for $x \ne 0$
$$
 \lambda x = \mu x \mbox{ implies } \lambda = \mu
$$
which could be easily seen as $\lambda x = \mu x \Leftrightarrow (\lambda - \mu) x = 0$ or by writing $\mu = \lambda + \xi$ and then reducing to $\xi \cdot x = 0$, hence $\xi = 0$ (also this is obvious by considering some component of $x$ if the vector space is finite-dimensional and $\cong K^n$ and then using multiplicative cancellation in the ground field).

But absolutely nowhere is this stated? I looked up all my textbooks and scripts, has this a cause? Do you know a reference where it is stated? Of course it is a trivial and easy to see fact, but that are other algebraic identities also, and assuming a beginning math student some introductory textbooks should mention it (at least as an exercise)?

Or is this fact simply not used anywhere?

Comment: It might be omitted simply because the equality of vectors tends to be more important in linear algebra than the equality of scalars.